# Xcode source control won't commit

Tags: xcode, git

Problem:

When I hit "Commit..." under the Source Control menu in Xcode, the window comes up blank and I get a colorful pinwheel that doesn't stop spinning, so I have to force quit Xcode.

[image: The commit window]

Details:

- It's not a problem with Xcode in general because I can still commit other projects.
- The version editor still works (I can still see previous commits I've made).
- I've let the pinwheel run for over an hour, and still nothing happens.
- I was able to commit this project up until a couple months ago.  Since then, I added a few files to it, edited it a bit, updated Xcode if I remember right, and updated macOS.
- Some of the files I added came from other projects.
- I've tried removing some of the files I added and then committing, but that didn't work so I added them back.
- I've tried cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, and restarting my mac.
- I don't know much about source control, but I don't have anything fancy set up with a team or anything, it's just a local repository.
- I've tried suggestions to delete various things inside the .xcodeproj file, to no avail.
- I have Xcode 9.4.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added big files (larger than 100mb) then sometimes Xcode has trouble with them. Try unstaging your commits and then committing them again. Finally try reverting back to the most recent version of your project and working from there.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick!  I didn't have any big files, but I did have a folder of lots of small files that added up to around 70MB.  For future reference, the relevant commands were git status, git reset, and "git add -A".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Sometimes selecting "Fetch and refresh status" works. The next time you go to commit the files will show up.

Answer (score 0):

I found that rebooting my computer fixed the problem.